# UnrecognizedPropertyException when mapping JSON to POJO

Tags: java, json, data-binding, jackson, pojo

I'm using the Jackson API to parse a JSON file to objects with the help of a set of POJO classes. But when the ObjectMapper gets to the @title field, the following UnrecognizedPropertyException error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "@title" (class gmit.Exit), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "title", "direction"])
 at [Source: C:\Users\Brian\Documents\Eclipse\Projects\AI_Project_Grail_Quest_3\bin\resources\game.json; line: 13, column: 24] (through reference chain: gmit.Location["location"]->Object[][0]->gmit.Location["exit"]->Object[][0]->gmit.Exit["@title"])
```

This is the JSON file being parsed in:

http://hastebin.com/qamacarumu.pl

I understand this is from the property not being recognized as the error states, but I'm not sure why as I've declared this field in the Exit POJO. Someone suugested adding @JsonProperty to the field like this, which didn't seem to work:

```
@JsonProperty("title")
private String[] title;
```

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this error? Or can you offer an explanation of why this error is being thrown despite there being a title field present in the Exit POJO?

These are the POJO's:

Location:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Location {

    private Location[] location;

    private String description;

    private String name;

    private Exit[] exit;



    public Location[] getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location[] location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getDescription ()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription (String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Exit[] getExit() {
        return exit;
    }

    public void setExit(Exit[] exit) {
        this.exit = exit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Location [location=" + Arrays.toString(location)
                + ", description=" + description + ", name=" + name + ", exit="
                + Arrays.toString(exit) + "]";
    }



}
```

Exit:

```
public class Exit {

    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String[] title;

    private String[] direction;


    public String[] getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String[] title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String[] getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }
    public void setDirection(String[] direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your annotation be `@JsonProperty("@title")`, since that's the name of the key in the JSON?
Also note, that Jackson comes with two different namespaces depending on your version. This can easily be a trap

- `org.codehaus.jackson`
- `com.fasterxml.jackson`

so make sure you use the correct annotation

Comment: okay I'll try the above solution, I did notice that if I suppress this error and run, the exit title and direction isn't printed when I print the location out as an array, every other value is populated except for title and direction which are null..any idea why this could be considering the values aren't null in the Json file?

Comment: I guess with "suppress this error" you mean to add the `@JsonIgnore` annotation. Basically you are telling Jackson that it shouldn't bother if it can't find those fields. Since nothing can be mapped to it they will be assigned `null`. The `@JsonProperty` annotation that you used is the way to go, except that you need to specify the correct JSON-key (i.e. `@title` and not `title`).

Comment: now I'm getting `Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: C:\Users\Brian\Documents\Eclipse\Projects\AI_Project_Grail_Quest_3\bin\resources\game.json; line: 13, column: 13] (through reference chain: gmit.Location["location"]->Object[][0]->gmit.Location["exit"]->Object[][0]->gmit.Exit["@title"])`

Comment: guess I need to change the types of the fields in Exit? @Maze

Comment: Title is a String and not an array of Strings, so change your class to reflect this, or your JSON structure

Comment: yeah figured that out, first time using JSON but it seems pretty powerful :)